# Font Awesome disappear in some connection

Tags: font-awesome

The icon on the official site does not appear. But when using another connection, the icon appears perfect, are there any settings that I can apply?

Firefox, chrome or Edge are the same

[image]

Comment: What, When, Where did you used those icons?

Comment: I access directly to the https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery page, but all the icons hide.

Comment: Seems to be browser issue!. try with other browser

Comment: However, when opening one of the icons (https://fontawesome.com/icons/abacus?style=solid), the icon appears. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Had the same issue. Was using firefox browser. Using chrome solved the issue.